# Parse string to Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

How to convert this string to array in PHP?

```
   "["COLOR","SIZE","TYPE"]"
```

I have read so many answers but they have a different string format  and also I found the `eval()` but Im not a fan of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: What format is your string in? If it’s JSON, use [`json_decode`](https://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: And BTW, what you posted here as already an array

Comment: you can do this manually with `str_replace` and `explode`.

Comment: So as Ryan suggested `print_r(json_decode('["COLOR","SIZE","TYPE"]'))`

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy way [demo link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$php_value = json_decode('["COLOR","SIZE","TYPE"]');
print_r($php_value);
```